# How Visual Basic 6 VB.Global.Load Sub works?

Tags: vb6

I have a problem: one of the forms in my project takes long time to load. Situation: 
With using debugger I go through code. When I reach row with `Load frmTest` (there is a specific form) it takes about 1.5 - 2 seconds to continue in Form_Load handler.

I tried to search for some documentation, but failed... well at least finding any information about what Load Sub does before Form Load event triggers.

So, how does the VB.Global.Load work?

[image: VB6 IDE Object browser VB.Global]

Comment: The biggest job it does it to initialize all the controls/activex components sited on the form (or anything in the global scope declared As New) so if you have any third party ones then that's something to investigate.

Comment: As mentioned, controls and activex components will be instantiated and initialized.  If there are a large number of controls, that could account for time. If any of the controls are data bound, time may be taken connecting to and reading from a database or other data source.

Comment: `Load frmTest` does *not* call `Load` in `VB.Global` as `Load` is implemented as a statement in the language. Subs that "cover" built-in statements are present in runtime typelibs *only* for the IDE to perform auto-complete or whatever for tips it can grok and show to devs. Using `F8` (step-into) will trace controls initializations, provided that these are project referenced (part of a .vbg project group) or their source is part of current project.

Comment: @wqw Why then it is shown as definition in object browser when you "Control+F2“ to it?

Comment: @MantasDaškevičius For a control array one can use `Load MyCtlArray(5)` but cannot call function `MyLoad` instead like in `MyLoad MyCtlArray(5)` as 5-th item in the control array is *not* initialized yet and this will err w/ index out of bounds. Once again `Load` is a statement not a function. The IDE can navigate to whatever it finds in the referenced typelib w/ no discrimination what is built-in statement or not. You can devise a typelib with a public function named `For` and search for it w/ `Shift+F2` I suppose (not `Ctrl+F2`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Alex K. for the answer:

> The biggest job it does it to initialize all the controls/activex
>   components sited on the form (or anything in the global scope declared
>   As New) so if you have any third party ones then that's something to
>   investigate.

Answer (score 1):

There're so many things that can go wrong.

That's how I would analyze this case.

1. Check if you have Form_Initialize method, if not - create it and check if delay's before or after this method's call.
2. Check if you have any private fields on a form level. If there're heavy objects there they may be initialized before the form Load and it may take the time. Especially actual for the COM objects.
3. If this happens for a single form only I would try to understand what's so special about this exact form and if needed remove everything to the ground to detect the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but it is not really what I asked for. I actually already tried all of that and found those speed problems. But thanks any way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this *is* VB6 (never heard of 'VB.Global.Load' in that context), see [Life Cycle of Visual Basic Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa242139(v=vs.60))

Comment: VB.Global.Load is the sub you use to load forms: `Load Form1`. At least this is the description when you load Load in object browser. The VB is the class library that contains static (I think) class Global which provides Sub Load

Comment: I stand corrected. I very rarely use the object browser, mainly because it often doesn't provide much information as you've found!

Comment: That's because you are supposed to press F1 for further help on the item. Object Browser has the binary definition and the Help topic ID.